# Overwrite font-size in phonegap

Tags: cordova, webview, font-size

I am building an application with phonegap for android and iOs. The problem I have is that although I have set a font-size within CSS some devices(for example even Nexus 5 with kitkat) have the webView rendering with different font-size than I have set(I set up an alert with the font-size and it was different).

CSS:

```
#menu {
  font-size: 10px !important; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#menu").css("font-size", "10px");

alert($("#menu").css("font-size"));
```

and nothing works, it prints me 9px.

I thought it was a chromium problem(as i know that kitkat is using chromium and the older versions weren't), but when i have put it online, on my chrome everything shows up perfectly.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another class overwriting your important rule

try:

```
body#menu {
  font-size: 10px !important; 
}
```

Comment: Tried, not working. My guess is that phoneGap overwrites it somehow.